# TYPO3 Extbase: combine multiple queries

Tags: php, sql, typo3, extbase

I want to select only $limit records from the table with the category $cat.

```
foreach($cats as $cat) {
    $query = $this->createQuery();
    $query->matching($query->equals('type', $cat));
    $query->setLimit((int)$limit);
    $result[] = $query->execute();
}
```

Is it possible to combine the query result so one query result?

Answer (score 2):

I think your query is something like ,

```
"SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE type IN ('".$cats."')"
```

Here $cats is an array of categories like,

```
$cats = array("cat1", "cat2", "cat3");
```

Then the extabse query will be,

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->matching($query->in('type', $cats));
$query->setLimit((int)$limit);
$result = $query->execute();
```

In the above query in() checks if a single-valued property exists in a multi-value operand.

For more details refer : http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/3-implement-individual-database-queries.html

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, I found another way that worked for me:

```
public function findAllLimitedByCategory($limit, $category){


    $cats = explode(",",$category);
    $result = array();

    foreach($cats as $cat) {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $query->matching($query->equals('type', $cat));
        $query->setLimit((int)$limit);
        $result[] = $query->execute()->toArray();
    }

    $out = array();

    foreach($result as $r)
        $out = array_merge($out, $r);

    return $out;
}
```

...but I have to sort the array by php with this solution

Comment: Ralf what kind of sorting you required, based on any field in the result array...

Comment: I'm sorting the array by date
    public function SortObjectByDatum($arr) {
   usort($arr, function ($a, $b) {
  
  if ($a->getDatum() == $b->getDatum()) {
    return 0;
  }
  return ($a->getDatum() > $b->getDatum()) ? -1 : 1;
   });
   return $arr;
 }

Comment: In case that you only want to get a few results of each category, this is the preferred solution. `usort()` should still perform well.

To do this with only one Query you need to use UNION in your statement or subqueries, but both are not supported by extbase. You need to model your query by hand and use `$query->statement()` to execute it, but it's more complicated and with only a few results there aren't any performance benefits. So I wouldn't recommend it.